# Как выполнить команду градл gradle -Doptd clean assembleRelease -i?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Нужно выполнить вот эту команду

```
gradle -Doptd clean assembleRelease -i
```

открываю `cmd`в папке проекта пишу ее и получаю вот такую ошибку

> C:\LocalGit\myDir\MyProject>gradle -Doptd clean assembleRelease -i
>   'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Как выполняются градл команды?

Что делаю не так?

Comment: В нормальном проекте по-умолчанию используется `gradle-wrapper` и запускается он командой `gradlew` вместо `gradle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cамый простой способ это вызвать `gradle` из `Android Studio` в проекте

[image: Gradle cmd]

Другой вариант это добавить путь исполняемого файла программы `gradle` в переменную `PATH` (реализация добавления переменной зависит от ОС).

Или же указать полный путь к `gradle` в команде

```
C:\PATH\TO\gradle[.exe] -Doptd clean assembleRelease -i
```